# Encrypting DB password with Jasypt causing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, jasypt, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have been following [This](https://www.ricston.com/blog/encrypting-properties-in-spring-boot-with-jasypt-spring-boot/) URL to encrypt my DB password using Jasypt in Spring boot application. From there, i found [This Github](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) url where i was trying to follow first and second approach. But when i tried running my application, i am getting below exception at application startup.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/PlaceholdersResolver
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerSyntheticBeanIfMissing(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:137) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at com.test.app.Core.main(Core.java:28) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [Core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [Core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [Core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [Core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.PlaceholdersResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[Core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

I am working on RabbitMQ application with Jasypt to encrypt DB password. Below is my pom.xml. Can anybody let me know why I am getting this error. You can replicate exception by copying my pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Core</groupId>
<artifactId>Core</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description>Core</description>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oracle-repo</id>
        <name>oracle repo</name>
        <url>http://download.oracle.com/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
        <version>5.1.40</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.12</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
        <artifactId>expiringmap</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.16.12</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are using a too new version of `jasypt-spring-boot`. Use an older version. Also remove the `spring-context-support` dependency as with that you are now mixing 2 versions of Spring 4.3.8 and 4.3.3.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Which version of jasypt-spring-boot you advice me?

Comment: Find the one that still s supports 1.5.

Comment: @M.Deinum : I updated dependency to 1.16 and the error is resolved. Thanks for the answer. Will be great if you post this as a answer so that i can accept. Also do you mind answering my https://stackoverflow.com/q/52148946/3349753 this question as i am unable to login DB using Jasypt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the dependencies for the 2.1.0 version of the `jasypt-spring-boot` library requires Spring Boot 2.0. You probably need to downgrade to an earlier version of the library.

Probably version 1.18 as that still has Spring Boot 1.5.10 as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.