# Unable to login DB using jasypt

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jasypt

Hi I am using below maven dependency in my Spring boot application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using below command to encrypt my DB password.

```
encrypt input="test" password=test algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

In my application.properties, i have below properties,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1234;database=TEST_DB
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=ENC(OPdJ9jOw7tbJR+MlptpCHg==)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.poolName=SpringBootHikariCP
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=50
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=30
spring.datasource.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements=250
```

In my application code, i am able to get decrypted value of spring.datasource.password property. But when i use `JDBCTemplate`, i am getting below exception.

### Edit :

Mistakenly added wrong stacktrace. Below is correct one. Due to 3 unsuccessful attempts, the password got expired.

```
[ERROR] 2018-09-03 04:50:45.578 [https-jsse-nio-8092-exec-9] util -  LOG  : Class :Controller|| Method :process || org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'test'. ClientConnectionId:ba0abe4d-014a-42d3-b39e-ec1efc0e7131
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:494)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:500)
at com.test.dao.AppDaoImpl.generateQuery(AppDaoImpl.java:77)
at com.test.dao.AppDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5d4e5540.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
at com.test.dao.AppDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb86c18b.generateQuery(<generated>)
```

It is not able to login to database. Below is my AppDaoImpl.java

```
    @Repository
public class AppDaoImpl implements AppDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public Integer generateQuery(String id) throws ImpsException {
        return jdbcTemplate.update(QueryConst.SQL_INSERT_QUERY, id);
    }
    }
```

Before jasypt, i was just autowiring my JDBCTemplate and everything was working fine. Now it is not able to login.

PS: I am running my application with

```
-Djasypt.encryptor.password=test -Djasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

Comment: Well the error message seems pretty clear to me `Reason: The password of the account has expired.` ... Renew your password.

Comment: @M.Deinum : I mistakenly added wrong stack trace. I have edited the same. Please let me know if i have to do any more changes in my code to make this work as i am able to print the DB password in logs.

Answer (score 1):

From the message  `Reason: The password of the account has expired.` its clear that password has expired.

Log in to SQL server as a system administrator. Change the password to something else. Make sure enforce password policy is off and then change the password back to the original password.

OR

Right click 'Username' and go to Properties

You can find 'Enforce password expiration' on login properties window, which needs to be unchecked.[image: see this image]

Comment: I mistakenly added wrong stack trace. I have edited the same. Please let me know if i have to do any more changes in my code to make this work as i am able to print the DB password in logs.